# cat program in Go

Tags: io, go

In order to learn Go, I've implemented the `cat` program in Go. I want to know if the code is idiomatic and what could be improved.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io"
import "os"

var errors int

func main() {
    catFilesOrStdin(os.Args[1:])
    os.Exit(getExitValue())
}

func getExitValue() int {
    if (hadErrors()) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func hadErrors() bool {
    return errors > 0
}

func catFilesOrStdin(files []string) {
    if len(files) > 0 {
        catFiles(files)
    } else {
        catStream(os.Stdin)
    }
}

func catFiles(files []string) {
    for _,file := range files {
        catFile(file)
    }
}

func catFile(file string) {
    stream, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        errors++
        return
    }
    catStream(stream)
    defer stream.Close()
}

func catStream(stream *os.File) {
    _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, stream)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        errors++
    }
}
```

Comment: I think perhaps you're going overboard with the number of functions. I also don't see a reason not to make it `func catStream(r io.Reader)` rather than require a `*os.File`.

Comment: Good point about the `io.Reader` instead of `os.File`, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

I'd put the `defer` statement in catFile *above* the call to catStream, not after.

You might want to consider `log.Fatal` if the `os.Open` fails.

If you're importing multiple packages, the standard is a single import statement with all the packages in parentheses.

The global `errors` variable technically *should* be protected with a `sync.Mutex`, but more importantly, `log.Fatal` on any error instead.

Comment: wrt `log.Fatal` on any error, although I'd probably do that if implementing something like this from scratch, that is not the behaviour of unix `cat`. E.g. `date | cat /nosuchfile -` gives a warning message and continues on (but exits with 1 instead of 0); this is the behaviour being implemented here.

Comment: Although, I would use the `log` package. Something like `log.SetPrefix("cat: "); log.SetFlags(0)` then `log.Println(err)` rather than explicitly `fmt.Fprintln` to `os.Stderr`. But that's more of a preference thing. You could probably wrap warning logging into a function that also did `errors++`.